# Can't Set Default in Twitter Bootstrap Toggleable Tab in Single Page Application

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, requirejs, single-page-application, durandal

I am using the Hot Towel Single Page Application template (uses require, durandal, knockout).  In this particular view, I am using a Twitter Bootstrap toggle tab and need to set a default selected tab when a user first enters the view.  What I have is not working.  Here is the view (CAApproval.html)-

```
           <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="width: 45%">
                <li><a id="btnMyCert" href="#home" data-toggle="tab" data-bind="click: SelectMyCerts">My Certificates</a></li>
                <li><a id="btnAll" href="#profile" data-toggle="tab" data-bind="click: SelectAllCerts">All Pending</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Here is the viewmodel (CAApproval.js)-

```
 define(['services/logger', 'durandal/system', 'durandal/plugins/router', 'services/CertificateDataService'],
function (logger, system, router, CertificateDataService) {
    var allCertificates = ko.observableArray();


    var activate = function () {
        logger.log('Certificate Approval View Activated', null, 'CA Approval', true);

        $('#btnMyCert a[href="#home"]').tab('toggle');

        // go get local data, if we have it
        return CertificateDataService.getallCertificates(allCertificates);

    };


    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        allCertificates: allCertificates,
        title: 'Certificate Approvals',
        SelectMyCerts: SelectMyCerts,
        SelectAllCerts: SelectAllCerts
    };

    return vm;

    function SelectAllCerts() {
            return CertificateDataService.getallCertificates(allCertificates);
    }
    function SelectMyCerts() {
            return CertificateDataService.getMyCertificates(allCertificates);
    }
});
```

I have even tried putting this jQuery directly in the view (did not work)-

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('#tab a[href="#btnMyCert"]').tab('show');
        });

</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the same tab is the default every time the user enters the view. For this case, add the **active** class to the list item you want to be the default.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a id="btnMyCert" href="#home" data-toggle="tab">
            My Certificates
        </a>
    </li>    
    <li>
        <a id="btnAll" href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">
            All Pending
        </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KEbQa/

Answer (score 0):

Glad that worked! But if you do want to set the active tab from your viewmodel instead (or do any other DOM manipulations for that matter) you would have better results if you used the the view callbacks provided by Durandal; [beforeBind, afterBind, viewAttached](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Interacting-with-the-DOM/). The problem you're having is that your jQuery DOM selector is called before the view is attached - which won't happen until:

1. The promise returned by your asynchronous data call is fulfilled
2. The view and viewmodel are bound (beforeBind, afterBind)
3. The bound view is composed into the DOM - after which the viewAttached callback is fired

Try moving your selector to a to viewAttached function in your viewmodel.

```
var viewAttached = function(){ $(....) };
```

Durandal is great, but if you don't have a good understanding of asynchronous functions (promises, Q) and the [view/viewmodel lifecycle](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks/) things can quickly get pretty hairy!

Hope this helps.